# Razor pages "asp-page" not linking to specified location, instead linking to current page

Tags: asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I'm seeing some unexpected (to me) behavior when using `asp-page` in my asp.net Razor Pages application. I have a folder structure like this:

```
Manage
  Index
  NewAccount
```

On the `NewAccount` page, I want to have a link back to the manage account page, `/Manage/Index`. I'd expect the following code to do this:

```
<p><a asp-page="/Manage/Index" asp-route-accountId="@Model.AccountId">Back to account view</a></p>
```

Instead of linking to the `/Manage/Index` page though, it's linking me back to `/Manage/NewAccount`! This makes absolutely no sense to me.

I've tried quite a few values for `asp-page`.

- `/Manage/Index`: Loads `Manage/NewAccount` as described
- `/Index`: Loads `/Index`, which is what I'd expect
- `./Index`: Loads `/Index`
- `/Manage`: Routes to `/Manage/NewAccount`

I know I could get this working using regular HTML `<a href=""></a>` code. But I'm trying to do this using canonical asp.net syntax. Plus I'd really like to use `asp-route` to pass query parameters, which you can't use with `href`.

I'm sure the issue is obvious to those of you who know razor pages better than I. I'd love an explanation of why `/Manage/Index` doesn't work as well, if someone knows. Thanks!

Comment: try <p><a asp-page="../Manage/Index" asp-route-accountId="@Model.AccountId">Back to account view</a></p>

Comment: Do you have an @page directive in the Index.cshtml file?

Comment: @Bosco Loads `Manage/NewAccount`

Comment: @MikeBrind Yes. The only way to navigate to `Manage/NewAccount` is through `Manage/Index`. The Index.cshtml is valid.

Comment: Having a very similar issue.. Been a while but did you find the solution?